# Directory search is Not working after using getfiles

Tags: c#

I am using Windows form on which I am using a textbox,folderbrowserdialog and listbox control and two button controls.The task is to retrieve specific file type say .txt from the folder in the textbox1. After getting specific file type from textbox1 I want to display it on listbox1.So I used directory.getfile option but it is showing me error of An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' .Can any one tell me what is wrong on my code.

```
namespace WinDataStore
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var t = this.Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
            string[] extensions = { ".txt", ".aspx", ".css", ".cs" };

            string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles("t", "*.*")
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            string[] p = dizin;
            listBox1.Items.Add(p);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `"t"`? `GetFiles` expects the path, while you provide "t".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change you code like

Check the value of text is not empty.

you can use addrange() method to add value to listbox(before it was adding array object to list box)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
            Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            //notification to user
            return;
        }
        //var t = this.Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
        string[] extensions = { ".txt", ".aspx", ".css", ".cs" };

        string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*")
            .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(dizin);
        //string[] p = dizin;
        //listBox1.Items.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass path of the folder in first parameter:

```
Directory.GetFiles(t.Text, "*.*")
```

instead of just passing "t".

Even you don't need to refer to `t` while you have `textBox1` in the same scope, you can directly use:

```
Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*")
```

Now add array to `listbox1`:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(dizin);
```

Comment: I tried both way so I put entire code here when i am clicking for second button it is showing me String[] Array.

Comment: You are adding array to the listbox, here is the mistake. Check updated code

Comment: yes that was the problem and your code is also working now

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in this way:

```
string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(t.Text, "*.*")
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
```

Becuase you put "t" that is an error, because t is not a string but a variable containing the folder, as I understood looking your code.

Answer (score 0):

The way your are trying to read the path from textbox is not correct. Also do below changes to your code. Also I think there is an issue in the way you're adding items to the listBox. I haven't tested this code. Please try and let me know if you have any issues.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = textBox1.Text;
        string[] extensions = { ".txt", ".aspx", ".css", ".cs" };

        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        var validFiles = (from file in allFiles from extension in extensions where file.ToLower().Contains(extension) select file).ToList();
        foreach (var validFile in validFiles)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(validFile, validFile));
        }
    }
```